# MS Access 2007 renaming shortcuts in custom groups to change the names of the objects

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, grouping, shortcut

In Access 2007 I create a lot of custom groups to organise the large number of queries and tables in a single database.  There are lots of individual sub queries that link up to larger queries.  In development, I find it necessary to frequently rename some of the queries permanently after they have been added to a custom group.

But Access only renames the shortcut that is in the group and not the actual object.  This causes broken references.  So I now have to remove an object from the group, rename it, then add back to the group.  This adds further problems if you have lots of queries and tables.

Is there any way to configure Access to rename the actual object and not just the shortcut from within a custom group?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot do this in Access. That's the idea of *shortcuts*. Actually, it is the same as in Windows (you can rename the shortcut but the object itself stays intact).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this in Access 2007 version, at least.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

Delete the shortcut, so the object is located in the unassigned objects group. In there, rename the object. Then drag the object back in the customized group.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible to do without deleting anything.  Here's how:

1. Switch the view type in the navigation panel to the type of object you're working with (queries or tables)
2. find the actual table and rename it (everything you see here will be actual objects and not shortcuts)
3. switch the view type back to Custom

This will change the name of the table while keeping the name of the shortcut in tact.  I tested this in Access 2013, and the old shortcut will now point to the new table name.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to your question - NO